# Adding an 'All' option into a codeIgniter form_dropdown

Tags: codeigniter

I have an array that returns locations from the database, which I am trying to output into a form drop down using the following code:

```
<?php form_dropdown('idLocation', $queryLocations, set_value('idLocation'); ?>
```

The `$queryLocations` has the `locationID` and the `locationName`.  And this above code works fine to display all locations, now I need to add an option called 'All' having `idLocation` as zero to appear at the top of location list.

Can someone please help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend the `$queryLocations` array with your values. Here's one way:

```
form_dropdown(
    'idLocation',
    array('0' => 'All') + $queryLocations,
    set_value('idLocation')
);
```

You could probably do this earlier, when you actually create the `$queryLocations` array as well.

```
$options[0] = 'All';
foreach ($results as $r) $options[$r->idLocation] = $r->locationName;
```

Something like that...